# jquery animate wont work

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

jQuery-newbie here.

I want to do a simple horizontal scroll function with two buttons. I want to do it with animate. But when I click on one of the buttons, nothing happens...

Heres the jQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#right-button').click(function {
        $('#box').animate({
        left: +="200px"
        }, "fast");
    });

    $('#left-button').click(function {
        $('#box').animate({
        left: -="200px"
        }, "fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<section id="main">
    <span class="scrollbutton left" id="left-button">(</span>
    <span class="scrollbutton right" id="right-button">)</span>
    <div id="box">
        <div class="column"></div>
        ...
    </div>
</section>
```

(I've also tried it with an a-Tag)

Aaaaand here's the css:

```
#main {
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    max-height: 480px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ddd;
}

#main #box {
    width: 2250px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#main .column {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 429px;
    border-left: solid 1px #333;
    height: 460px;
}

.scrollbutton {
    font-family: "WebSymbolsRegular";
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

It's probably a very naive error, but I just have no idea what it is... I hope you can help me :)

PS: You can find it here: http://patrickmanser.ch/pixelsword/

Comment: "200px" + "200px" == "200px200px" & 200 + 200 == 400

Comment: yup, I canged that :) Still wont move

Comment: Have you tried to write `$('#right-button').click(function () {`
instead of `$('#right-button').click(function {`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#right-button').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
        left: "+=200px"
        }, "fast");
    });

    $('#left-button').click(function() {
        $('#box').animate({
        left: "-=200px"
        }, "fast");
    });
```

function() ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#right-button').click(function {
        $('#box').animate({
        left: "+=200px"
        }, "fast");
    });

    $('#left-button').click(function {
        $('#box').animate({
        left: "-=200px"
        }, "fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax of animate function, At

```
left: +="200px"
```

+= sign should be within the quotes. so it should be like this

```
left: "+=200px"
```

Do same with the other parameter.

Additionally,

1. you should move .column instead of #box.. .column is inside #box. I think it should be moved rather.
2. put position:relative to .column.
3. remove float:left from .column at least.

see working fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/gaLKc/

Comment: There were couple of more problems with your script see the updated answer above.

Comment: It worked! the function() solved it... I just didn't see that! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#right-button').click(function {
    $('#box').animate({
    left: "+=200"
    }, "fast");
});
```

not "200px" it should be "=+200"

Comment: Have you tried giving a number of seconds instead of "fast" ?

Comment: do the other jquery effects work? if they don't, it might be a problem with importing the jquery library!

Comment: Yes, the image slider works. You can see this at http://www.patrickmanser.ch/pixelsword